# Refining an answer to x decimal places in java

Tags: java

I have an assignment and I need to get an input from the user to refine an answer to an x(the input of the user) number of decimal places. I'm going to refine my answer until there aren't any changes in the x decimal place.Can you please help on how I could achieve this answer?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve, but I think you want to accept a number and then round it up as the user specifies it.

Java's BigDecimal http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html class has all the functions you may need for this purpose. Please don't use the primary data types (float, double) as they will result in rounding errors sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true what @Thihara answers, maybe you need a bit simpler approach. Unless you need the precision of `BigDecimal`, you can do this:

```java
    int x = 4;
    double value = 3.141593;

    long answer = (long) (value * Math.pow(10, x));
```

The point is: multiply the value by 10^x and then convert to `long` (or `int`). Of course, this only works for small `x`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of issues floating around here, that you should be aware of.

The first is that if you use a floating point number to represent your answer, you cannot represent every possible real number so you almost definitely will get rounding errors. Check out http://floating-point-gui.de/ for great information about this.

Secondly, when you print a `float` or `double` value, Java does some magic with it so that it looks nice. See [`Float.toString(float)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toString%28float%29) and [`Double.toString(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29) for more information.

So in reality, if you enter

```
double answer = 3.14159265;
```

it is stored as

```
3.141592650000000208621031561051495373249053955078125
```

which you can see using

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(answer));
```

So assuming you get your answer as a `double` (or `float`), you should use `BigDecimal`'s [`setScale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,%20int%29) method. Also, if you want to limit the decimal places that your user can choose to the number visible when you print the `double` as a string, pass `String.valueOf(answer)` to `BigDecimal`'s constructor.

Here is a little program that demonstrates how to do this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double answer = 3.14159265;

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String input = null;
    do {
        System.out.println("Answer: " + answer);
        System.out.println("How many decimal places do you want? ");
        try {
            input = in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                int decimalPlaces = Integer.parseInt(input);
                if (decimalPlaces < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Enter a positive value.");
                } else {
                    BigDecimal scaled = new BigDecimal(
                            String.valueOf(answer));
                    if (decimalPlaces > scaled.scale()) {
                        System.out
                                .println("Answer does not have that many decimal places.");
                    } else {
                        scaled = scaled.setScale(decimalPlaces,
                                RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
                        System.out.println("Rounded answer: " + scaled);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Not a valid number.");
            }
        }
    } while (input != null);
}
```

Most of the code is error/input checking. The real work is done by `setScale`. Just keep in mind that there are many boundary conditions when working with floating point numbers, and you should be good!

Comment: While your answer is (of course) true, useful and also important to know for a Java programmer, I think it is a bit "to much" for someone starting with programming. As the questioner is "very new to Java" and this is an assignment, I think it would help if you would add some more "basic" information to the beginning of your answer and not start with the "weird" floating point issues…

Comment: @siegi I agree with you, and I might be entirely out of line by posting this answer, but here are my reasons for doing so: 1) none of the other answers either in this question or others I looked at satisfied me. 2) I was curious how difficult it was to do this properly (if you simply multiply by `10^x`, convert to int, and divide by `10^x` you run into all kinds of issues). 3) I think it's more valuable to become aware of floating point numbers rather than learn how to round an answer to a certain number of decimal places. Also, this is not a 'weird' floating point issue, it is very standard.

Comment: Good reasons! :-) With "weird" I meant that it is probably looking weird/strange/… for a beginner. I know it is perfectly normal, that's why I've put it in quotes ;-)